# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: While Parsing data form an API contains Japanese Characters

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I was trying to parse an `API` response with `Scrapy` and `JSON` but it's generating me an error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:`

I tried all the Japanese `encoding` types from [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) but none worked. Hope there is a solution from you guys.

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

class MakuakeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'makuake'
    start_urls = ['https://api.makuake.com/v2/projects?page=1&per_page=15&category_code=technology']

    def parse(self, response):
        json_rsp = json.loads(response.body).encode("encoding-type-jps").decode("utf-8")
        print(json_rsp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `response.text`

```
import scrapy
import json

class MakuakeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'makuake'
    start_urls = ['https://api.makuake.com/v2/projects?page=1&per_page=15&category_code=technology']

    def parse(self, response):
        json_rsp = json.loads(response.text)
        print(json_rsp)
```